# Set Selected Item in combobox by SelectedValue attribute

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a combobox with StaticResource called Currencies, Currencies is an ObservableCollection of some class

in this class i have a parameter called CurrencyID.
I have another class called Item which have a parameter called CurrencyID.

i want to set the Item.CurrencyID  from the combobox, for that i use ValueSelected and ValueSelectedPath with a converter from comboboxitem to the CurrencyID.

and it works.

next i want to select the comboboxitem from the CurrencyID of the Item class.
But it always show unselected comboboxitem.

Here's the relevant code:
XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <converters:sp_GetCurrencies_ResultToID x:Key="sp_GetCurrencies_ResultToIDConverter"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key ="Currencies" Source="{Binding Currencies}"/>
</Window.Resources>


<ComboBox x:Name="cmbCurrencies" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Currencies} }" SelectedValuePath="{Binding CurrencyID, Mode=TwoWay}"  SelectedValue="{Binding Item.CurrencyID, Converter={StaticResource sp_GetCurrencies_ResultToIDConverter}}" DisplayMemberPath="CurrencyName" Width="150" Height="30" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5"/>
```

Converter:

```
public class sp_GetCurrencies_ResultToID : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
            using (PricingManagerEntities db = new PricingManagerEntities())
                return db.sp_GetCurrencies((long)value,null).FirstOrDefault();                
        else
            return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            return (value as sp_GetCurrencies_Result).CurrencyID;
        }
        else return null;
    }
}
```

Inside the code i set Item.CurrencyID = 1.

I'm getting also this error, in which i think it's related:
BindingExpression path error: 'CurrencyID' property not found on 'object' ''ItemsViewModel' (HashCode=45202739)'. BindingExpression:Path=CurrencyID; DataItem='ItemsViewModel' (HashCode=45202739); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name='cmbCurrencies'); target property is 'SelectedValuePath' (type 'String')
The program '[12436] PricingManager.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Classes don't have parameters. Do you mean a property? `SelectedValuePath` should not have a binding. It should just be a string, the name of a property on the combo item viewmodel. Probably "CurrencyID". Maybe that binding you have should be on `SelectedValue`. What is the purpose of the converter?

Comment: The purpose of the converter is to take an int value and return sp_GetCurrencies_Result which is an object, the int value is a unique number for each sp_GetCurrencies_Result

Comment: No, that's what it does. I can see that from the code. *Why* does it do that? What problem do you think it solves? Tell me the part that isn't trivially obvious from your question.

Comment: What is in `Currencies`? Tell me the name of the class it contains.

Comment: you right, i thought i needed a converter to take an object i set it's ID into a viewmodel field, but after removing the converter and set the SelectedValuePath to string and not binding it works.